# How to add the more than one button on the right side of the navigation bar in objective.c

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have added the one button on right side of the navigation bar with this code, but i want to add the three buttton like this but i am adding with this code, I think button is overlap on one place , i am able to see only one button on right side of navigation bar.

```
         UIButton* modalViewButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
              [modalViewButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(modalViewAction1:)          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       UIBarButtonItem *modalBarButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithCustomView:modalViewButton1];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = modalBarButtonItem1;
        [modalBarButtonItem1 release];
```

Comment: i want to add three button like this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want isn't offered in the API by default, so what you'll need to do is create your own UIView subclass that displays 3 buttons. Then set your navigationItem to have its rightButtonItem be a new UIBarButtonItem with a custom view like so:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:YOUR_VIEW];
```

Comment: can u give me some sample code for the belove.
when i click on any right side button of navigation bar ,i want to go on another view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assigning 3 buttons to `rightBarButtonItem` then of course you are overwriting the same `right bar button item` ... there is only one `rightBarButtonItem`

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it here on the image below for instance is to use a UISegmentedControl as a custom view of the UIBarButtonItem :
[image]
Then you inherit the multiple boutons that are part of the segmented controls.
On this image I use the same for left and right buttons of the navigation bar.